# Find a sparse surrogate matrix that performs as good as the original one

Tags: optimization, sparse-matrices

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a dense matrix and $x$ is a given vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. How can one solve the following problem or its relaxation to find a sparse matrix that acts like $A$?

$$
\min_{\tilde{A}} ||Ax -\tilde{A}x||^2\\
{\text{s.t. }||\tilde{A}||_0\leq s}
$$

where $s \in \{1, \dots, m\times n -1\}$ and $||\tilde{A}||_0$ is the number of nonzero elements.

Comment: Please take a look at [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508).

Comment: As you say in the reason for the bounty, you "need to solve this question", it would be helpful to share with Readers (present and future) what makes the problem important to you.  This kind of context increases the likelihood that Answers will be of a nature and level that you will find useful.

Comment: While you describe as the "origin" of this another [one of your Questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4147256/relationship-between-matrices-whose-singular-values-are-the-same) in a Comment below the accepted Answer, that post sheds no light on the role of the "given vector" $x$ in the present Question.  As the Answer below recognizes, fixing $x$ has the effect of making the problem not so much about finding a matrix $\bar A$ that "acts like $A$" as it is about approximating vector $Ax$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While describing an optimization algorithm  for a relaxed version of this problem, I think I found a simple analytical solution for the original problem.

I'll assume $x \neq 0$. Notice that none of the rows of $\tilde A$ should have more than one non-zero entry. (There would be no benefit in that.)

If $s$ is greater than the number of rows of $\tilde A$, then each row of $\tilde A$ will have one non-zero entry (at most), and the optimal objective function value will be $0$.

Otherwise, the optimal $\tilde A$ will have $s$ nonzero rows. Which rows of $\tilde A$ should be nonzero? It should be the rows of $\tilde A$ that correspond to the $s$ largest (in magnitude) components of $Ax$. Those components of $Ax$ will be neutralized, and the optimal objective function value will be the sum of the squares of the remaining components of $Ax$.

Solved!

---

Below is my original solution using the proximal gradient method. You can see at the end where I start to recognize the simpler solution.

A common technique is to penalize the $\ell_1$-norm of $\tilde A$ to encourage $\tilde A$ to be sparse. This approach has the benefit that the $\ell_1$-norm is convex, so the resulting optimization problem is a convex problem.

In more detail, you can solve the optimization problem
$$
\tag{1} \text{minimize} \quad \| \tilde Ax - b \|^2 + \lambda \| \tilde A \|_1
$$ where $b = Ax$ and $ \| \tilde A \|_1$ is the sum of the absolute values of the entries of $\tilde A$. The optimization variable is $\tilde A$. Now solve this optimization problem with a method such as the proximal gradient method or an accelerated proximal gradient method. Tune the value of $\lambda > 0$ by trial and error to achieve the desired sparsity level.

One thing that might be a little confusing is that our optimization variable $\tilde A$ is a matrix, whereas typically optimization algorithms are described with the assumption that the optimization variable is a vector. But, we can just reshape $\tilde A$ into a vector, as follows. Let $a_i^T$ be the $i$th row of $\tilde A$, so
$$
\tilde A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1^T \\ \vdots \\ a_m^T \end{bmatrix},
$$
and let $a$ be the column vector obtained by vertically concatenating the column vectors $a_1, \ldots, a_n$:
$$
a = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{bmatrix}.
$$
(I have defined $a_i$ so that it is a column vector.)
Notice that
$$
\tilde A x = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} x^T & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & x^T & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & x^T
\end{bmatrix}}_{X} \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_m \end{bmatrix} = Xa
$$
The optimization problem (1) can now be expressed equivalently as
$$
\tag{2} \text{minimize} \quad \| X a - b \|^2 + \lambda \| a \|_1.
$$
The optimization variable is the column vector $a$.

---

Now that we've formulated our optimization problem, the next step is to solve it using the proximal gradient method. The proximal gradient method minimizes functions of the form $f(x) + g(x)$, where $f$ is convex and differentiable (with Lipschitz continuous gradient) and $g$ is convex and "simple" in the sense that its proximal operator can be evaluated efficiently. (Technically we also need to assume that $g$ is lower semi-continuous, which is typically satisfied in practice. We do not require that $g$ is differentiable -- that's what makes the proximal gradient method so useful.)

The proximal operator of $g$ with parameter $t > 0$ is defined as follows:
$$
\text{prox}_{t g}(a) = \arg \min_u \, g(u) + \frac{1}{2 t} \|u - a \|_2^2.
$$
The parameter $t > 0$ can be viewed as a "step size" which controls how severely we are penalized for moving away from the input vector $a$. Intuitively, the proximal operator of $g$ reduces the value of $g$ as much as possible without straying too far away from $a$.

The proximal gradient method iteration (with step size $t > 0$) is
$$
a^{k+1} = \text{prox}_{t g}(a^k - t \nabla f(a^k))
$$
for $k = 1, 2, \ldots$.
The vector $a^0$ can be initialized to all zeros.
Intuitively, the proximal gradient method repeats the following two teps: First we take a step in the negative gradient direction to reduce the value of $f$, then we evaluate the proximal operator of $g$ to reduce the value of $g$.
Convergence is only guaranteed if the step size $t$ satisfies the step size restriction $t \leq \frac{1}{L}$, where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant for the gradient of $L$. There is also a line search version of the proximal gradient method where the value of $t$ is chosen adaptively at each iteration. The line search procedure does not require knowing the value of $L$.

In our case, we'll take
$$
f(a) = \| Xa - b \|^2 \quad \text{and} \quad g(a) = \lambda \| a \|_1.
$$
The gradient of $f$ is
$$
\nabla f(a) = 2X^T (Xa - b).
$$
It can be shown that the proximal operator of $g$ (with parameter $t > 0$) simply "shrinks" each component of the input vector $a$ towards the origin by a distance $\lambda t$, stopping if we hit the origin.

With the above facts, you're now ready to implement the proximal gradient method to solve problem (2).

---

Here are some further thoughts which I believe are rather important but which I'll need to think more carefully about to check to see if I'm making an error.

I think we will run into a problem in that some columns of $X$ are highly correlated with each other. In particular, the first block of columns of $X$ are all scalar multiples of each other, and likewise for the second block of columns of $X$, etc. When columns of $X$ are highly correlated with each other, the $\ell_1$-norm tends not to promote sparsity as much as we would like. That's because the $\ell_1$-norm can't measure a difference between a solution where just one entry of $a_i$ is non-zero and a solution where that entry of $a_i$ is "spread out" so that now all entries of $a_i$ are non-zero
while the value of $Xa$ is unchanged.

I think the simplest way to handle this is to notice that only one component of each vector $a_i$ needs to be nonzero. In other words, for any candidate vector $a$ I believe we can find a candidate vector $\hat a$ for which each block $\hat a_i$ has only one non-zero entry, and such  that $\hat a$ is just as good as $a$ in the sense that $Xa = X \hat a$.

Thus, I believe we can reduce the size of the problem by assuming that only the first entry (let's say) of each block of $a$ is non-zero. We now have fewer optimization variables, and we can proceed in a similar way.

Strangely enough, in this approach I think the problem becomes fully separable, meaning that the problem reduces to solving a bunch of independent subproblems, one subproblem for each block of $a$. (And for each subproblem, the optimization variable is a scalar. I think we could even derive an analytical formula for the solution to each subproblem.) I need to check my thought process here carefully because it sounds like too much of a simplification.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Please do not erase any of your explanation later. My problem with your solution is that you are solving the relaxation problem not the original one. Is there any way to show that under some condition $l_1$ solution is indeed $l_0$ solution like the case when we have restricted isometry property for $\min_x ||Ax-b||^2\text{ s.t. }||x||_0 \leq \hat{s}$?

Comment: @Sepide If I'm not mistaken, I think that now I've found an analytical solution to the original problem.

Comment: That would be great! The origin of the problem I posted is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4147256/relationship-between-matrices-whose-singular-values-are-the-same where I found the sparse matrix using iterative hard thresholding which now has almost half zero in it. Strangely, almost all singular values are the same and I do not know why?

Comment: Just to make sure I am following your answer. You are saying when $s$ is less than number of rows, just zero out $m-s$ rows that generate smaller numbers than the other $s$ ones? And, for the the case where $s$ is greater than the number of rows why objective value is zero and how you can make it zero by some nonzero entries?

Comment: @Sepide "for the the case where $s$ is greater than the number of rows why objective value is zero and how you can make it zero by some nonzero entries?" Let $b = Ax$. Let $x_1$ be the first component of $x$. Let's assume (for simplicity) that $x_1 \neq 0$. Then you can take $\tilde A_{11} = b_1/x_1$, and set the remaining entries of the first row of $\tilde A$ to $0$. And you can set $\tilde A_{21} = b_2/x_1$, and set the remaining entries of the second row of $\tilde A$ to $0$. And so on. With $\tilde A$ chosen like this, we have $\tilde A x = b$, so the objective function value is $0$.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. When in the constraint $s \geq m$, can we always get a solution where $||A||_0\leq m$?

Comment: @Sepide Yes: The solution $\tilde A$ that I described in my previous comment (which addressed the case $s \geq m$) has $\| \tilde A \|_0 = m$, because there is only one nonzero entry in each row of $\tilde A$.